# Django Send Mail in IIS 10

Tags: django, iis, iis-10

My company requires production/development in IIS. I've developed an app that sends email notifications on form submittal. Emails are sent with a google mail account. It works great when I run the app on the django development server (manage.py runserver). When I run the app on IIS server, I am unable to send emails. I get the SMTPSenderRefused 530, b'5.7.0 Authentication Required error.

I have searched hi and low for documentation that would address this problem, with no luck.

```
web.config settings for smtp

<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="name@gmail.com">
            <network defaultCredentials="false" host="smtp.gmail.com" password="password" port="587" userName="name" />
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

```
django settings.py

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USE = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASS')
```

Since django is sending the email through its `django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend`, I wouldn't think I need to do any settings in IIS (i.e. web.config file etc)?

Any suggestions of where to read up would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Update - If I set the IIS SMTP to default (port 25), it throws a [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed. I've tried to add the typical mailSettings code to the web.config file but then the aforementioned SMTPSenderRefused error is thrown.

Comment: What Django settings are you using for your email configuration for your production app?

Comment: Added email settings from settings.py file

Comment: I think I might know why. Windows 10 Pro (what I'm running) does not include SMTP virtual server like previous versions. I believe I need that application in order to relay emails from django to the smtp server of choice.

Comment: What verification method are you using? Can you show me your web.config file?

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this issue?